# View elements of an array when debugging in Netbeans

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

Netbeans has a variable tab that appears when debugging. It works great for for example booleans as I see the name of the variable and its value (e.g. "true") and Strings (as I see e.g. "Dog") but I in the case of arrays, for example an array of Strings, I see something like #57(length=13) but would like to see its contents i.e. {"a", "b", "c", "d"}. Is this possible in Netbeans?

Comment: I haven't used Netbeans, but I'd *expect* arrays to just be expandable to see their contents - like a directory in a file explorer...

Comment: You're right - there is a tiny "+" sign I haven't seen. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A very old question, but I've found an easy solution for **Netbeans 12.0**.

When debugging, in the **Variables** tab, right-click on the table's header (for example **Value** header), and check **String value: String representation of the value**.

A new column **String value** will be added with the toString() value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add expressions to the watch expressions. They are expandable.

Answer (score 0):

u can use the "Expression Evaluation" windows. It's less comfortable then "Variables" window but still helpful. 
to get this windows go to "WIndows" --> "Debugging" --> "Expression Evaluation".

there if you have, for example, array of type "items_t" called "items" , u just type "items[0]" and it shows you all what inside that index.

I still have not managed to find out how to print the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

In variable tab, just add a new watch,

like ***table_name@table_size**